# Gettext returns without error, but there's no translation

Tags: php, gettext

I've got

`/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po` and
`/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`

And I've made this script:

```
$folder     = 'locale';
$domain     = 'messages';
$lang       = 'en_US.utf8';

$directory = dirname(__FILE__)."/../../$folder/"; // checked with is_dir and directory exists

putenv("LANG=en_US");
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $lang);
bindtextdomain($domain, $directory);
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
```

But when I try to translate something (French to English):

```
 echo _("Accueil")."<br/>"._("Oui");
```

it doesn't work. But the words are translated in the `.mo` files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works in my environment. (I put locale folder and test.php in same folder not / ). Maybe you can try to get return value of bindtextdomain : `echo bindtextdomain($domain, $directory);` for checking *.mo in the correct folder?